# Javascript Loop within a loop Logic to produce Specific output

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, echo

I good with php but javascript is not good with me, my english also not very good but im explaining everything as best and slowly in step by step.
I  make calculation for charges for a telecom service using javascript. I know similar logic with in php has to be used but Then I stuck.

```
  /prices is json from server as see below.
var prices  =   [{"brand":"Airtel (Waridtel) Ug","numbering":"25670","price":"40"},
                 {"brand":"UTL ug","numbering":"25671","price":"30"},
                 {"brand":"Airtel Ug","numbering":"25675","price":"40"},
                 {"brand":"MTN Ug","numbering":"25677","price":"20"},
                 {"brand":"MTN Ug","numbering":"25678","price":"20"},
                 {"brand":"Orange Ug","numbering":"25679","price":"30"},
                 {"brand":"Safaricom Ke","numbering":"25470","price":"30"},
                 {"brand":"Safaricom Ke","numbering":"25471","price":"30"}]
```

a user  provide the various telephone Numbers in  comma seperation string

```
   //contacts
   cdest = '245772306640,256754306640,25471624525,2567825689754,2563989654285,4588623566', 256782658974;
```

we use brand prefix to find brand.
if  contacts prefix is equivalent to  price numbering in json, then that is conctact which is owned by that brand. I  calculate how many contact per brand and total cost basing on contact list user provide.

Expecting output is shown below.
brand(number of contacts)::total cost 
Example MTN Ug(3)::60 , Airtel Ug(1), Safaricom Ke(1)::30,

Im also like to place any number with no a brand under a universal brand wich is called International with no a price assign as see below example
International(2)::default,

Here Im very confuse with two loops, im not understand how I can loop , count and echo but Im good with transfer of php knowledge so far I create double loop, but then I confuse again.

```
//explode numbers;
dest =  cdest.split(",");

// loop through brands and numbers. 
//plan is to create create array like (brand1 =>countbrand1,brand2=>countbrand3, etc)

cd = Array();
for( var i=0; i<dest.length; i++ )
{
    $x.each(prices, function(index, m) {
        if(dest[i].indexOf(m.numbering)==0)
        {
            cd[m.brand]+=1; 
        } else
        cd[International]+=1;
        });
}
```

In php I simply loop on cd now and get output. I try for js, but dont know how to echo the key of array in Javascript. javascript is bullying me whole day. If you make good answer, please you show in slow step by step. Im very thankful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check this fiddle that I have created from your code. May help you 
http://jsfiddle.net/GSeZ9/

```
var prices  =   [{"brand":"Airtel (Waridtel) Ug","numbering":"25670","price":"40"},
                 {"brand":"UTL ug","numbering":"25671","price":"30"},
                 {"brand":"Airtel Ug","numbering":"25675","price":"40"},
                 {"brand":"MTN Ug","numbering":"25677","price":"20"},
                 {"brand":"MTN Ug","numbering":"25678","price":"20"},
                 {"brand":"Orange Ug","numbering":"25679","price":"30"},
                 {"brand":"Safaricom Ke","numbering":"25470","price":"30"},
                 {"brand":"Safaricom Ke","numbering":"25471","price":"30"}];

var cdest = '245772306640,256754306640,25471624525,2567825689754,2563989654285,4588623566, 256782658974';

var dest =  cdest.split(",");

// loop through brands and numbers. 
//plan is to create create array like (brand1 =>countbrand1,brand2=>countbrand3, etc)

var cd = {};
for( var i=0; i<dest.length; i++ )
{
    $.each(prices, function(index, m) {
       // if(dest[i].toString().indexOf(m.numbering.toString()) != -1 )
            //alert(dest[i].indexOf(m.numbering));
        if(dest[i].toString().indexOf(m.numbering.toString()) == 0)
        {
            if( cd[m.brand] == undefined)
                   cd[m.brand] = 1;
            else
                cd[m.brand]+=1; 
        } //else
            //cd[International]+=1;
        });
}
for (var key in cd) {
   alert(key + " = " + cd[key]);
}
```

Comment: the only problem i get now is that value of brand not incrementing using  cd [m.brand]+=1

Comment: no its fine its work ok, it was issue with space, so i trim and all verygood

Answer (score 0):

In php arrays are used for many things, but in javascript arrays don't have keys. Objects do. What you have in the `prices` variable is an array of objects. To loop an object you can use the following syntax:

```
for (var key in p) {
  // do something
  // the key has the name `key` and to get the value, you
  // can type p[key]
}
```

This is your inner loop. You got the outer loop right. This is how you will loop an array with the name `dest`:

```
for( var i=0; i<dest.length; i++ ) {
     var member = dest[i];
     // do something with member
}
```

With the outer loop we will get every object in the array and assign it to a variable with the name `member`. (You may think of a better name, of course)
So your final code will have to look something like this:

```
for( var i=0; i<dest.length; i++ ) {
    var memeber = dest[i];
    for (var key in member) {
       // do something with the keys and values - print them for example.
    }
}
```